# Symfony2 YAML parsing fails

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have this content in YAML:

```
Foo:
    bar:    |
            Foo bar.
```

And it works fine, but this:

```
Foo:
    bar:    |
            40 % Foo bar.
```

Fails:

> ParameterNotFoundException: The parameter
>   "foobar" has a dependency
>   on a non-existent parameter " Foo bar.".

Based on the error, it clearly occurs right where the percent sign % appears. Is there some way to encode it or make it not fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the %something% syntax is used by Symfony Dependency Injection Container to reference DIC parameters. I think that you should somehow escape the %; as a first try I would go for one of those:

```
40 %% Foo bar .
40 "%" Foo bar .
"40 % Foo bar ."
```

I didn't find a 100% sure answer in Symfony, so go for tries ;)

Comment: The last would be the correct way of doing it. Also note that a non-escaped % can cause errors if you ever parse your yaml with non-symfony parsers.

Answer (score 2):

So in short, use `%%` when you want `%` in yaml value.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html

All percentage signs (%) in the format string must be doubled to escape the character. Without escaping, values might inadvertently be interpreted as Service Parameters.